# problemas con el proyecto de c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

resulta que quiero hacer referencia a un ViewModel que tengo  como se muestras en la siguiente imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sin embargo me muestra el error de que falta una referencia de ensamblado, podrian darme una ayuda para solucionar el probema ya busque en internet pero la verdad no entiendo muy bien porque me esta mandando este error.

gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Hola!
Desde mi parecer veo dos posibilidades:

1. Renombres los proyectos de tu solución, evitando en lo posible el punto **dado que interfiere en el uso de las referencias** como muestras en la imagen. Por último, usa otros caracteres como `_`, `-` si quieres hacer una distinción similar.
2. Modifiques la línea de `namespace` en la clase a la que haces referencia, quitando el punto y colocando algún nombre más adecuado (no estoy seguro de si sea más engorroso o no sea tan buena práctica).

```
namespace NombreProyecto.Models
```

Saludos y nos cuentas cómo te va.

Answer (score 0):

Solamente dejalo asi

```
@model Clothbazar.ViewModels.CategoryViewModels

@model Namespace.Carpeta.Clase
```